# Android YUV to grayscale performance optimization

Tags: android, performance, image-processing, optimization

I'm trying to convert an YUV image to grayscale, so basically I just need the Y values.
To do so I wrote this little piece of code (with frame being the YUV image):

```
imageConversionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        size = frame.getSize();

        byte nv21ByteArray[] = frame.getImage();

        int lol;

        for (int i = 0; i < size.width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size.height; j++) {
                lol = size.width*j + i;
                yMatrix.put(j, i, nv21ByteArray[lol]);
            }
        }

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(yMatrix, bitmap);


        imageConversionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - imageConversionTime;
```

However, this takes about 13500 ms. I need it to be A LOT faster (on my computer it takes 8.5 ms in python) (I work on a Motorola Moto E 4G 2nd generation, not super powerful but it should be enough for converting images right?).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you want to dive into OpenGL shaders, take a look at [Android RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute) as the sample (RGB to greyscale RGB) is similar to what you want to do. Does require some familiarity with C as RenderScript is C99.

Comment: I will have a look at OpenGL. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would assign `size.width` and `size.height` to a variable. I don't think the compiler will optimize this by default, but I am not sure about this.

Furthermore Create a `byte[]` representing the result instead of using a `Matrix`.
Then you could do something like this:

```
int[] grayScalePixels = new int[size.width * size.height];
int cntPixels = 0;
```

In your inner loop set

```
grayScalePixels[cntPixels] = nv21ByteArray[lol];
cntPixels++;
```

To get your final image do the following:

```
Bitmap grayScaleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(grayScalePixels, size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Hope it works properly (I have not tested it, however at least the shown principle should be applicable -> relying on a byte[] instead of Matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Probably 2 years too late but anyways ;)

To convert to gray scale, all you need to do is set the u/v values to 128 and leave the y values as is. Note that this code is for YUY2 format. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa904813(v=vs.80)#yuy2) document for other formats.

```
private void convertToBW(byte[] ptrIn, String filePath) {
    // change all u and v values to 127 (cause 128 will cause byte overflow)
    byte[] ptrOut = Arrays.copyOf(ptrIn, ptrIn.length);

    for (int i = 0, ptrInLength = ptrOut.length; i < ptrInLength; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            ptrOut[i] = (byte) 127;
        }
    }
    convertToJpeg(ptrOut, filePath);

}
```

For NV21/NV12, I think the loop would change to:

```
for (int i = ptrOut.length/2, ptrInLength = ptrOut.length; i < ptrInLength; i++) {}
```

Note: (didn't try this myself)

Also I would suggest to profile your utils method and createBitmap functions separately.